# Resource is not a Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This code causes force close exception on Emulator(API 18) and works in ASUS Nexus 7(API 21)

```
<View
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

If I am replacing `@color/light_gray` with `#EBEBEB` works perfectly on both device.

Exception is

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080060 a=-1 r=0x7f080060}
```

So I moved to drawable on following code,

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/login_btn_selector"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin" />
```

This one throws following exception,

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/login_btn_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020095
```

So I tried to place the `login_btn_selected.xml` in  `res/drawable-hdpi-v4/` folder, Then it says duplicate file occur between `res/drawable-hdpi/` and `res/drawable-hdpi-v4/`, So I removed it from `res/drawable-hdpi/`, Then again same resource not found exception in v4 folder,

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/login_btn_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020095
```

So finally I came to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

The problem is,

1. I want to know is this problem in emulator only or in real device too.
2. If in real device too means how can I overcome this?

   I want to use `@color/light_gray` instead of hard coding, Also I want to use drawable selectors.

**NOTE:** I have deleted and recreated the Emulator, no use. I have tested on API 19 emulator also, same issue.

Any solution will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path)

Comment: @VahidHoseini I already updated my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because my color resource file is under `\res\values-21` folder, Now moved it to `\res\values\` folder, Now app works fine. thank you friends.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you don't have the background of an imageView set to `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, otherwise older devices will have this error:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struck with the same problem in the recent app I made. In my case, the problem was I put an image in the folder called drawable-v21, which is not available in older android API.

The solution is to put your drawable in drawable-...dpi folders too.

Answer (score 0):

Your color resource must reside in an Android resource file (i.e.: in the `colors.xml` file).
Android would not complain **where** you set it, but it **must** be defined as a **color resource**.

I.e.:

```
<color name="light_gray">#ebebeb</color>
```

**[EDIT]**

The names appear not to match...
See this line:

```
android:background="@drawable/login_btn_selector"
```

Then you say: `So I tried to place the login_btn_selected.xml`.

It seems to be the cause of

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/login_btn_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020095.
```

Comment: like this only I have defined bro.. it is working perfectly in nexus 7.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way of doing this is, first create a xml file inside the "drawable" folder and do something like below.

e.g. light_gray.xml then do something like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/light_gray" />
    </shape>
```

once you have saved it.

change you code like below.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@ drawable/light_gray" />
```

But make sure to put the file light_gray.xml only to "drawable" folder. Do not put the same file to "drawable-hdpi or drawable-hdpi-v4 and so on"