# FloatingActionButton to launch new activity

Tags: android

I really appreciate your effort towards helping me out with this challenge. I want to launch a new activity when user click on the floating action button. Here is my code:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Action replaced", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,WriteMessage.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WriteMessage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Create text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

But when I run the app on my device, I get "Unfortunately, ... has stopped." What could be the issue and how do I resolve it. Thank you

Here is the log:

```
    08-31 23:38:53.816 13960-13960/technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    08-31 23:38:53.816 13960-13960/technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415f3bc0)
    08-31 23:38:53.826 13960-13960/technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler, PID: 13960
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler/technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler.WriteMessage}:
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler.WriteMessage.onCreate(WriteMessage.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020050 a=-1 r=0x7f020050}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2159)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler.WriteMessage.onCreate(WriteMessage.java:11) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    08-31 23:38:59.602 13960-13960/technology.airwaves.com.smsscheduler I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13960 SIG: 9
```

Here is the XML file (activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Here is the XML file for app_bar_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/appHeader"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

I intend to launch a new activity when the FloatingActionButton is pressed

Comment: Add your log please

Comment: You need to provide us with a crash stack trace which you can get from the adb log

Comment: Okay sir. Am on it

Comment: @Joe also provide the XML file of activity you are trying to launch via FAB

Comment: `Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class ImageButton` 
`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):` 

Basically you have inflation error in `WriteMessage` Activity'xml file . it would be better if you provide the **xml** file and how you set **Drawable** resource id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource is not a Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915699/resource-is-not-a-drawable)