# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.efftronics.android.eEmployee, PID: 17148
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                      at com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Activity.Entry.Unplanned_Work_Entry.onCreateView(Unplanned_Work_Entry.java:97)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020055 a=-1 r=0x7f020055}
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2109)
                      at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3558)
                      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
                      at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:64)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                      at com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Activity.Entry.Unplanned_Work_Entry.onCreateView(Unplanned_Work_Entry.java:97) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: when I click on enter your work status button, It is showing this error]

when I click on that button, I am navigating to another fragment and in that fragment i am setting layout like this.

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unplanned_works_entry, container, false);

unplanned_works_entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/entry_show"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

entry_show

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_dt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="11"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_tod"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:editable="false"
    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_tod" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/entry_nodata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/entry_cardView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/input_date"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/entry_list_plans"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_date"
        android:padding="20dp">
    </ListView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to android.Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is issue with your `@drawable/border` , `@mipmap/ic_tod`  image check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915699/resource-is-not-a-drawable

Comment: In most cases this exception thrown when system couldn't find view by it's id or found view has different type. Post code where you're binding xml views to code view classes. Something like Button btn = findViewById (R.id.button);

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020055 a=-1 r=0x7f020055}` it looks like you are using some wrong drawables

Comment: Thank you so much for your support sir.issue with the image@NileshRathod